# Mutiple wildcard domains on same subscription with Plesk Obsidian

Tags: command-line, virtualhost, plesk, wildcard-subdomain

I’m using Plesk Obsidian and I need to host an application on it (a website builder).
On this application, users can create websites on subdomains, and the application will determines what website to show itself by checking the subdomain. Multiples main domain are available.

- website1.domain1.com
- website2.domain2.com
- website3.domain3.com

All the main domains (**domain1.com**, **domain2.com** and **domain3.com**) and also all the subdomains must:

- Go to the same directory in server
- Be secured by a SSL certificate

Also, as users can also have a custom domain, I need to be able to add it and set the same directory in server and get a SSL certificate.

I’ve tried to create a service plan and a subscription and added the first domain (**domain1.com**) to it.
For the others domains, I’ve added an alias (**domain2.com** and **domain3.com**).

The problem is that I can’t add the wildcard for those 2 domains and have a wildcard SSL neither.
So accessing to **anything.domain2.com** result to a **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** error.

For others domains set as alias, SSL need to be regenerated each time we add a new domain and they're are bonded to the main domain...

---

If it's not possible through Plesk interface, I'm not against build a custom script launched in command line.
However, I don't know were I can put those custom generated virtualhosts without risking to be erased on Plesk update.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a wildcard SSL as far as you use a CA that admits wildcards on the SAN (which nowadays are almost all of them).

Concretely, if you want free certificates issued by Let's Encrypt, you just need to follow the following steps:

1. Log in to Plesk
2. Install the Plesk extensions **SSL It!** and **Let's Encrypt**
3. Go to **Domains > domain1.com > Hosting Settings**
4. Make sure **SSL/TLS support** is enabled
5. Go to **Domains > domain1.com > SSL/TLS Certificates**
6. Click on **Install > More options > Install a free basic certificate provided by Let's Encrypt**
7. Select explicitly **Secure the wildcard domain**
8. Click on **Get it free**

Same for the rest of the domains.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't answer to the part "Go to the same directory in server". All domains and subdomains must have the same DocumentRoot.